# Error in SAML response processing: No SAML assertion found in the SAML response

Tags: amazon-cognito, saml, adfs, idp

I've configured Cognito to use SAML Identity Provider and did all the setup on AD side, AD accepts the request and allow me to sign-in, then it responds to the configured idpresponse endpoint with the SAMLResponse form data value as you can see in the image below, but Cognito returns a `302` redirect with

```
location: http://localhost:3000/auth/callback#error_description=Error+in+SAML+response+processing%3A+No+SAML+assertion+found+in+the+SAML+response.+&error=server_error
```

[image]

I'm not sure what is going on, I tried to modify the POST request to idpresponse via curl and it is definitely reading the SAMLResponse form data because if I modify it I get invalid response error.

How can I troubleshoot it?

Comment: did you find any solution?